# Switch to different app in different desktop instead same desktop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

I have 2 windows of Chrome opened in Display 1 & 3. Beside that, there is Terminal run in Display 1. Display 2 has some windows from other apps. In this case, I offten switch between Terminal in Display 1 and Chrome in Display 3.

When I open Terminal in Display 1 and do <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> window switch to Chrome in Display 1, instead of Display 3. Currently, I have to shift right/left the space twice to switch it.

Is there shortcut key to accomodate this case?

Answer (score 2):

There are many variants on this question...

In short, Spaces is not designed to accommodate any app on ***more than one Space***.

So the simple answer is, "No."

Possible alternative workarounds...

- Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  to switch between open windows of the app you just switched to.
- Use dedicated key commands to switch to a specific Space rather than App - by default  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  plus  <kbd>[number]</kbd>  - & remember where each one lives. This is my preferred method, which I've been using since Spaces was invented.

Comment: To activate the second possibility go to System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Mission Control and activate the ticks "Switch to Desktop 1" and "Switch to Desktop 2".

Comment: Sometimes I use "Ctrl"+"Number", but number of space is hard thing to remember for me especially when work with many windows. Edit: Actually when I move Chrome in Display 1 to Display 2, I can easily move between terminal in Display 1 and Chrome in Display 2/3 just with "Cmd ⌘"+"Tab". It just my 2 cents

Comment: I sort my Spaces in 'patterns' of 'like' apps... eventually you just remember the numbers. Moving a window to a specific Space can be done by holding the title bar, then switching to a Space; the window will move with you - but it cannot be remembered if the app now occupies more than one Space.